# Error in @Query , Repository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Maybe error in `@Query` due to the fact that my entity have relation ?
Which the Repository contain error.

> Error creating bean with name 'clickRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract
>   java.lang.String
>   com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository.ClickRepository.sent(java.lang.String,long)!

Controller

```
 @Autowired
private ClickService service;

/*
    i.e. information about fullname_client, id_banner sent to server from client
*/
@RequestMapping(value = "/sentemail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String sentClick(@RequestParam ("fullnameClient") String fullnameClient,@RequestParam ("idbanners") long idbanners) {

    return service.sent(fullnameClient, idbanners);
}
```

Repository

```
@Query("SELECT c.fullnameClient FROM Click AS c join c.idBanner Banners b WHERE b.idBanner = :idbanners AND c.fullnameClient = :fullnameClient")
String sent(@Param("fullnameClient") String fullnameClient, @Param("idbanners") long idbanners);
```

Entity Click

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id_click", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
private long idClick;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "id_banners", nullable = false)
private Banners idbanners;

@Column(name = "fullname_client", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String fullnameClient;
```

Entity Banners

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id_banner", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
private long idBanner;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "banners")
private Set<Businessbanner> businessbanners;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "idbanners")
private Set<Click> clicks;
```

Error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'clickController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.ClickService
>   com.qoobico.remindme.server.controller.ClickController.service; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'clickServiceImpl': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository.ClickRepository
>   com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.ClickServiceImpl.clickRepository;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'clickRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract
>   java.lang.String
>   com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository.ClickRepository.sent(java.lang.String,long)!

Comment: Maybe query error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your param names differ. Try this:

```
 @Query("SELECT c.fullnameClient FROM Click AS c join c.idbanners b WHERE b.idBanner = :idbanners AND c.fullnameClient = :fullnameClient")

    String sent(@Param("fullnameClient") String fullnameClient, @Param("idbanners ") long idbanners);
```

**Update**

Ok your join was wrong.. instead of c join c.IdBanner.. it should be c.idbanners.

Comment: but Click also Red color underline

Comment: Change file in question. Add repository, controller, entity

Comment: Maybe error in @Query due to the fact that my entity have reltion ?

Comment: " i have updatd thee post "  ok . i try it.

Comment: The source can not be found, which describes in detail how to do complex queries. Tell me if there is something material. I have four tables are linked, obtained from two input data table Click, it is necessary to get a fourth column of the table, and the whole process of finding the column passes through the four tables

Comment: You should create a new post for that mate. This one was about wrong @Param configuration and wrong joining syntax. Do you still have problem regarding that original query? Lets not mix too many things in one thread, i wont be useful for other users of the forum

Comment: in my  @Query SELECT c.fullnameClient, column are taken from Entity or my DB ?

Comment: the hql query relates to entity fields.. eventually it is translated to your db's native sql by hibernate.. that is done under the hood.

Comment: Does it clear your concerns? And is the query working?

Comment: My concerns not made.

Comment: "the hql query relates to entity fields.. eventually it is translated to your db's native sql by hibernate.. that is done under the hood. "  thanks

Comment: ok i missed one detail in the query. Try now the update in the post

Comment: "FROM Click AS c join c.idbanners b "  or  "FROM Click AS c join c.idbanners Banners b"

Comment: FROM Click AS c join c.idbanners b

Comment: Thank, now open Chrome. Next, i will improve @Query

Comment: new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897719/how-to-create-a-request-for-a-complex-query-spring-query