# How to create a request for a complex query? @Query jpql spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jpql

How to create a request for a complex query in `JpaRepository` with the use of `@Query`?
I am concerned about the relationships between entities. They may affect the preparation of the request.

Needed query SQL, my version @Query:

Comment: your just asking about whether the query is valid? Your concerned with query performance?

Comment: I do not know how to create complex queries correctly.
I also have not found a suitable literature, technical English is difficult for me.

Comment: you can also add hibernate tag.. that actually what the question is about.

Comment: Sevlet download file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914092/how-change-servlet-which-download-single-file-but-can-folderfew-files-in-fold

Comment: @NewWave, your deleting of the original code in your question, makes this question incomplete and uneuseful for anyone. Downvoting for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so more advisable way of declaring your query would be :

```
@Query( "SELECT bu.email " +
               "FROM Businesscentr bu
                       INNER JOIN bu.bannersSet bs
                       INNER JOIN bs.clicks c " +
               "WHERE c.fullNameClient = :fullNameClient" // optional 
      )
```

You only use the old join style when you have to join by non-primarykey values.

Comment: need add in ClickRepository  import entity.Businesscentr ?

Comment: dont think so.. you are returning a plain string and not passing anything

Comment: and it does not start a complex query

Comment: I change request, change class. nothing helped

Comment: @Query( "SELECT bu.email " +
             "FROM Businesscentr bu INNER JOIN bu.bannerSet bs INNER JOIN bs.clickSet c " +
             "WHERE c.fullNameClient = :fullNameClient" // optional
     )

Comment: Where condition :idBanner ? paste in WHERE Banner.idBanner = :idBanner AND c.fullNameClient = :fullNameClient ?